# How to teach NHibernate to use the returned scalar of a stored procedure used in custom sql-insert?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

We have an NHibernate mapping where we have to use custom stored procedures for inserts, updates and deletes. We have the mapping as follows.

```
<class name="MyNamespace.MyClass" table="[MYTABLE]">

    <id name="Id" column="MYTABLE_ID"></id>

    ...

    <sql-insert check="none">
      EXECUTE SP_MY_TABLE_INSERT
      @p1 = ?,
      @p2 = ?
    </sql-insert>

</class>
```

We use `check="none"` due to some legacy reasons.

The above mentioned stored procedure returns the inserted ID as a scalar. However, when we commit the NHibernate transaction, the returned ID is not populated into the entity instance so we still see the value `0` in the `Id` property.

How could we teach NHibernate that the returned scalar should be treated as the inserted ID?

**UPDATE**

I've tried to use the `trigger-identity` generator which in my understanding kind of addresses this but I had no success, the `Id` still remains `0`.